# Trace Rails application called methods into a graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, graph, trace

I would like to generate a **graph** from a Rails application. Not about its database, but for every *methods* that are called after a web query (inside controllers, helpers, partials).

[Just like this one](http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5296/5508075654_e659cc9044_o.png) (by [@tenderlove](http://twitter.com/tenderlove))

This could help me a lot to detect loops and making optimizations.

Do you know a cool Ruby or Rails plugin for this?
Thanks!

**Edit:**
and this could be awesome, in order to solve a

> stack level too deep

Answer (score 0):

Use ruby-prof and a profiling data visualization tool like kcachegrind.